# How to create Azure NSG flow log with Traffic Analytics using Bicep

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-nsg

I'm currently using bicep to deploy NSG flow log with Traffic Analytics

I'm using the below BICEP template to create NSG Flow Log with Traffic Analytics.

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

@description('Name of the Network Watcher attached to your subscription')
param networkWatcherName string = 'NetworkWatcher_${location}'

@description('Name of your Flow log resource')
param flowLogName1 string = 'Microsoft.NetworkVisual_Studio_Subscription_NSGNSG_10.0.0.64_27'
param flowLogName2 string = 'Microsoft.NetworkVisual_Studio_Subscription_NSGNSG_10.0.0.96_27'
param flowLogName3 string = 'Microsoft.NetworkVisual_Studio_Subscription_NSGNSG_10.0.0.128_27'

@description('Region where you resources are located')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Resource ID of the target NSG')
param existingNSG1 string = '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NSG_10.0.0.64_27'
param existingNSG2 string = '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NSG_10.0.0.96_27'
param existingNSG3 string = '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NSG_10.0.0.128_27'

@description('Log analytics workspace resource Guid')
param workspaceId string = 'xxxxxx'

@description('Log analytics workspace region')
param workspaceRegion string = 'northcentralus'

@description('Log analytics workspace resource id')
param workspaceResourceId string = '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/xxxxx'

@description('Retention period in days. Default is zero which stands for permanent retention. Can be any Integer from 0 to 365')
@minValue(0)
@maxValue(365)
param retentionDays int = 0

@description('FlowLogs Version. Correct values are 1 or 2 (default)')
@allowed([
  1
  2
])
param flowLogsVersion int = 2

@description('Storage Account type')
@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
  'Standard_GRS'
  'Standard_ZRS'
])
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

@description('Storage Account Name')
param storageAccountName string = 'flowlogs${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

@description('Storage Account ID')
param storageId string = '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/MuraliRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxx'

resource sa 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {}
}

resource networkWatcher 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers@2019-11-01' = {
  name: networkWatcherName
  location: location
  properties: {}
}

resource flowLog 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs@2022-01-01' = {
  parent: networkWatcher
  name: flowLogName1
  location: location
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    flowAnalyticsConfiguration: {
      networkWatcherFlowAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        enabled: true
        trafficAnalyticsInterval: 60
        workspaceId: workspaceId
        workspaceRegion: workspaceRegion
        workspaceResourceId: workspaceResourceId
      }
    }
    retentionPolicy: {
      days: retentionDays
      enabled: true
    }
    format: {
      type: 'JSON'
      version: flowLogsVersion
    }
    targetResourceId: existingNSG1
    storageId: storageId
  }
}
```

I have a doubt on how to enter the value of multiple NSG ID. For example if i have 100+ NSG in a subscription how to enter all the values of NSG ID. BICEP is giving a condition "You are limited to 256 parameters in a Bicep file". Kindly advise on how to solve this issue.

Comment: you can always pass an array as parameter

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Thomas, you can create an array to store all existing NSG Ids and provide them to the network watcher resource using a `for` loop.

I tried achieving your requirement by referring to the [sample template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/quickstart-configure-network-security-group-flow-logs-from-bicep?tabs=cli) from MS Doc and was successful as showed.

```bash
param networkWatcherName string = 'NetworkWatcher_${location}'
param flowLogName string = 'FlowLog1'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param retentionDays int = 0
param flowLogsVersion int = 2
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_GRS'
param existingNSG array = [
'/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NRMS-yl6zhhens2a5iVNet1'
'/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-newjins'
]

var storageAccount = 'flowlogs${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' = {
  name: storageAccount
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {}
}

resource networkWatcher 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers@2022-01-01' = {
  name: networkWatcherName
  location: location
  properties: {}
}

resource flowLog 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs@2022-01-01' = [for nsg in existingNSG: {
  name: '${networkWatcherName}/${flowLogName}_${uniqueString(nsg)}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    targetResourceId: nsg
    storageId: storageAccount.id
    enabled: true
    retentionPolicy: {
      days: retentionDays
      enabled: true
    }
    format: {
      type: 'JSON'
      version: flowLogsVersion
    }
  }
}]
```

[image]

Refer here for multiple ways of traversing the [`for loop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#loop-syntax)  in bicep.

Comment: Thank u Jahnavi, its working. I have one more doubt regarding the ExistingNSGid, each and every time it will be challenging to provide the value for Existing NSG ID. Is there any way to execute a script to get the NSG value from the RG's and pass as a parameter in BICEP template. In future any changes made in the nsg creation template, the existing NSG ID parameter which we use in BICEP template will not affect.

Comment: You can use [`Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworksecuritygroup?view=azps-10.4.1) to retrieve the Nsg Id's from the resources and store it in one `json`  format file. Pass this parameter file while deploying the bicep by including `--parameters <filename.json>` along with the `az deployment group create` command. @CharismaticDevelop

Comment: Hi Jahnavi. Noted the above. But what will be the value i need to provide in BICEP parameter file for Existing NSG ID.
For Example, the above BICEP template iam deriving the Existing NSG id as a parameter, in that case what is the value i need to pass over there.

**param existingNSG array** = [
'/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NRMS-yl6zhhens2a5iVNet1'
'/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-newjins'
]

Comment: You can just declare it as `param existingNSG array = []`. No need to pass any ID's if you are using parameter file separately. @CharismaticDevelop

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi. Also, i would be requiring the flow log name as "Microsoft.Network followed by subscription name and NSG name". How this can be achieved? Do i need to write powershell script for that also

Comment: Yes, use `concat` and construct a name structure according to the requirement. @CharismaticDevelop

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Let me check and get back to you if i have any doubts. @Jahnavi

Comment: Its not working. Currently iam using a classic pipeline for build and in release pipeline iam providing the powershell script to get the value of Existing NSG id, but its giving me an error on existing NSG id parameter only. Kindly find the below error for your kind reference "##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern".
Kindly help me @Jahnavi

Comment: Also if i tried to run azure-pipelines.yml and iac validation for that in Build pipeline. In the release pipeline iam receiving the following error "##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'existingNSGIds' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array', but received a value of type 'String'.". But i have provided array only for that. Kindly help me on it @Jahnavi